# applying class from a variable

Tags: angular

I'm currently assigning conditional classes as :

```
<div [ngClass]="{
        'circle': (shape == 'circle'|| shape == 'circletosquare'), 
        'square': (shape == 'square'|| shape == 'squaretocircle')
    }">
```

Along with the conditional classes, I also want to insert a class from a variable called *customclass*, is this possible without having to use a custom function ?

I've tried without success:

```
<div [ngClass]="{
(customclass):true,
        'circle': (shape == 'circle'|| shape == 'circletosquare'), 
        'square': (shape == 'square'|| shape == 'squaretocircle')
    }">
```

Comment: just `[ngClass]="myVariable"` or `[ngClass]="{'other':shape=='circle',myVariable:true}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplish this by separating out the conditional classes into their own class directives like so:

```
<div [class.circle]="shape == 'circle'|| shape == 'circletosquare'" 
     [class.square]="shape == 'square'|| shape == 'squaretocircle'"
     [ngClass]="customClass">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `[ngClass]="customClassVariable"`

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  customClass = 'bg-red';
}
```

app.component.css

```
.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
} 

.bg-green{
    background-color: green;  
}
```

app.component.html

```
<h1 [ngClass]="customClass">
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</h1>

<button (click)="customClass='bg-red'">Red</button>
<button (click)="customClass='bg-green'">Green</button>
```

Find here stackblitz example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wwsvac